# Number of snake configurations in simple snake game

Tags: combinatorics

How do I calculate the total number of different snake configurations in a simple snake game? The length of the snake will always be $3$ and the playing field is $5\times 5$.

My thought process goes like this: The head of the snake can be in $25$ different squares, then the first tail-block must be next to the head, which there is $4$ options of unless the head is next to the wall, which equals $12$ squares and then there is only $3$ options. If the head is at a corner there is only $2$ options for the tail.

This should give $25*4 -(12*1 + 4*2)$ combinations for the first two blocks.
But then I run into problems since I can't figure out how to calculate the number of "first-tail" blocks that is next to a wall or in corner to use the same method for the third block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be counterintuitive, but it is easier to start with the middle square of the snake.  Now the two other squares have to border the square you start with, so you just choose one to be the head and then another to be the tail.  You then have $4 \cdot 2 \cdot 1+12\cdot 3 \cdot 2 +9\cdot 4\cdot 3=188$ possibilities.

Comment: Oh yes that was way smarter. I guess I didn't explicitly stated so but since it matters which square is the head shouldn't it be your solution times 2?

Comment: Yes, if you distinguish head from tail my combinations should become permutations and that multiplies by $2$.  I agree that makes sense.  Updated.